# foreigns key in android fts4 tables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-search, fts3

I have the following sql tables

Parent(_id,name)
Kid(_id,name,parent_id)//where parent_id is foreign key
Toy(_id,name,…,kid_id)//where kid_id is foreign key

right now I have queries that get all the Kids of a given Parent and also all the Toys for a given Kid.

There is a new need to include a search feature in the app. For that I need to change to an FTS4 table. How do I define the fts4 table so as not to lose the foreign key lookup capability? I am not experienced in fts by any margin. But I have read about docid vs rowid. Can I use docid for the foreign key values? Will someone please provide an example such as

CREATE TABLE Kid USING fts4(rowid, name, docid); //where docid is actually parent_id

Answer (score 0):

FTS tables are not really like real tables; think of them as indexes.

FTS tables should contain only text columns; storing the `parent_id` in an FTS table does not make sense. Furthermore, the `docid` is the same as the `rowid`, and should be the same as the primary key of the 'real' table.

So the tables should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Kid (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    parent_id INTEGER REFERENCES Parent(_id)
);
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE Kid_FTS USING FTS4 (name);
```